# XML Parser using SAX java Swing

Tags: java, xml, swing

I have a small project to complete. I have to parse an XML file and then display onto a user interface (swing). I did some research and tried out SAX parsing. Now, I am thinking how can I convert the object model into a UI. 
Here is the tutorial link I found: 
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/

Comment: Could you post fruit of your code , you tried?

Comment: How do you imagine it looking? What interactions do you want to perform?

Comment: There's not a question here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here we go for what you want is done.**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class JTableComponent {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JTableComponent();
    }

    public JTableComponent() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Creating JTable Component Example!");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        DefaultTableModel aModel = new DefaultTableModel() {
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                return false;
            }
        };

        Staff s1 = new Staff("vinod1", "BCA", "A", "10000");
        Staff s2 = new Staff("vinod2", "BCA", "A", "20000");
        Staff s3 = new Staff("vinod3", "BCA", "A", "30000");
        Staff s4 = new Staff("vinod4", "BCA", "A", "40000");
        ArrayList<Staff> l = new ArrayList<Staff>();// here you will get parser
                                                    // object this is as sample
        l.add(s1);
        l.add(s2);
        l.add(s3);
        l.add(s4);
        Iterator<Staff> is = l.iterator();

        String col[] = { "firstname", "lastname", "nickname", "salary" };
        aModel.setColumnIdentifiers(col);
        JTable table = new JTable(aModel);
        while (is.hasNext()) {
            Staff t = is.next();
            String firstname = t.getFirstname();
            String lastname = t.getLastname();
            String nickname = t.getNickname();
            String salary = t.getSalary();
            String temp[] = { firstname, lastname, nickname, salary };
            aModel.addRow(temp);
        }
        table.setModel(aModel);
        panel.add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

**Bean for you shown xml file**

```
public class Staff 
{
    String firstname= "";
    String  lastname ="";
    String nickname = "";
    String salary = "";

    public Staff(String firstname,String lastname,String nickname,String salary)
    {
         this.firstname= firstname;
         this.lastname =lastname;
         this.nickname = nickname;
         this.salary = salary;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }
    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }
    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }
    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
    public String getNickname() {
        return nickname;
    }
    public void setNickname(String nickname) {
        this.nickname = nickname;
    }
    public String getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }
    public void setSalary(String salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

May be the XMLEditorKit  http://java-sl.com/xml_editor_kit.html would help.
It allows to parse XML files and show them in a JEditorPane/JTextPane.

You can get the soruce code and add your own representation.